# Asynchronous services, Database connection C#

Tags: c#, database, sockets, asynchronous

I've been working on a project and one of the goals of the project is that multiple clients should access a database on a local network as such: [image: A diagram of the basic idea]

The basic logic of a synchronous connection is to check the client's input, if it's invalid the service returns an error, else it would execute SQL code in the database and return the data:
[image: A diagram of a synchronous client connection]

The problem I am facing is making it an asynchronous service.

The research that I have done tells me that I need to create a type of list/array of socket connections which will execute the requests synchronously, in a FIFO (*First In First Out*) style.

The questions I have are:

1. How does one listen to an incoming connection and add it to a List/Array that is synchronous?
2. How does one keep the connection alive when it's waiting for the request to be handled?

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use an established technology like WCF, which will give you asynchronous endpoints for your service contracts for free? Rolling your own socket server is tricky enough without adding asynchronous processing to the mix.

Comment: Im not sure why you wouldn't use one of the pre-scaffolded styles like Web API, Web Service, WCF etc. When these run they effectively use registered asynchronous endpoints. if your simply reading data from a database you can code your endpoint to do the single task. Each time the endpoint is hit, it will run on a separate thread. there is no need to manage your connections/threads in the way you speak of. There is also Node.js that may be worth a look but pretty different architecture,

Comment: I did not know about this, I'll be researching WCF.

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate your help :)

Comment: This is a pretty big question. Basically, you are asking how to make a worker thread pool and retain a connection back to the various callers.
If you are going to roll your own --it's not that hard--, start with the blocking queue. Each client creates a request. Each request has a token like a guid. Then stuff each request into the queue. Then worker threads pull requests out, and put each answer into a result message for the client to receive.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx